# Login across browsers?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have a requirement. If User login into application in one browser(IE) then if user tries to open the same application in another browser (FF) then FF should not prompt for the credentials because he has already logged in and kept IE open.

Is it possible in java/html/jquery?

Comment: Probally try using the users ip adress? if he allready logged in on that adress the other browser knows that? But if more people on the same network use the same website it wont work that well i think :P

Comment: The most reasonable answer to the question is "No". The requirement cannot be met due to technical limitations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to be possible, it would require different browsers to share some information (e.g. session id, cookie value).

Since even the [Web Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) introduced in HTML5 is not shared across browsers, you **can't** do this without the assistance of browser plugins (note: you could do this with a Java Applet, but it would require users approval to share information with other browsers e.g. via files).

The most that you could do is check the IP of the client, and at server side you could tell if there is already a logged in user from the same IP but we all know the IP can be the same for many users that are behind a proxy server for example, so this solution is **not satisfactory** but *could be sufficient in some limited cases* e.g. if the web application is only used from a local network (and where IP uniqueness can be guaranteed).